# Firebase function Stripe error

Tags: node.js, firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting this error message every time I try to create an external account for my custom stripe user.

[image: External account]

[image: Error message]

Here's my actual function:

```
exports.createExternalAccount =      functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/sources/{pushId}/token').onWrite(event => {
         const source = event.data.val();
         console.log('SOURCE', source);
        if (source === null) return null;
      return admin.database().ref(`/users/${event.params.userId}/customer_id`).once('value').then(snapshot => {

         return snapshot.val(); 
      }).then(customer => {
          console.log('CREATE EXTERNAL FOR COSTUMER', customer);
          const source = event.data.val();
         return stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(customer,{ 
             external_account: source
        });
      });
    });
```

I tried to add a currency, but still not working:

```
exports.createExternalAccount =        functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/sources/{pushId}/token').onWrite(event => {
     const source = event.data.val();
     console.log('SOURCE', source);
    if (source === null) return null;
  return admin.database().ref(`/users/${event.params.userId}/customer_id`).once('value').then(snapshot => {

     return snapshot.val(); 
  }).then(customer => {
      console.log('CREATE EXTERNAL FOR COSTUMER', customer);
      const source = event.data.val();
     return stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(customer,{ 
         external_account: source, 
         currency: 'usd'
    });
  });
});
```

Does anybody know how to solve it?

This is my payment source function

```
exports.addPaymentSource = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/sources/{pushId}/token').onWrite(event => {
  const source = event.data.val();
  if (source === null) return null;
  return admin.database().ref(`/users/${event.params.userId}/customer_id`).once('value').then(snapshot => {
    return snapshot.val();
  }).then(customer => {
    return stripe.customers.createSource(customer, {source});
  }).then(response => {
      return event.data.adminRef.parent.set(response);
    }, error => {
      return event.data.adminRef.parent.child('error').set(userFacingMessage(error)).then(() => {
        return reportError(error, {user: event.params.userId});
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: What error are you receiving now that you added currency? @John

Answer (score 1):

When you're making the [Create a Source](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_source) request, ideally through [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) or [Stripe.js/v3](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js), you should also pass a [`currency`-argument](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_source-currency).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I should add a payment source before creating an external account? I just added my payment source function in my question.

Comment: Sorry.  I think you misunderstood my recommendation.  No `customer` record is involved in this solution.  You simply create the source, as you were already doing, *but* you also add a `currency`-argument to that request when you do.